# Mongoose - How to add an object in a sub sub document array?

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I can add an item into a sub document array but I can't add an item into a sub sub document array..

Here is my Mongoose schema :

```
var botSchema = {
  "name" : String,
  "type" : String,
  "keyword" : String,
  "active" : Boolean,
  "cron" : String
};

var apiSchema = {
  "name" : String,
  "key" : String,
  "secret" : String,
   bots:[botSchema]
};

var userSchema  = {
    "email" : String,
    "password" : String,
    apis : [apiSchema]
};

module.exports.User = mongoose.model('user',userSchema);
```

How can I add a bot item to an existing API item ?

I have no problem when adding an API to the User. I do this :

```
    User.findByIdAndUpdate(
    userId, {
        $push: {
            apis: api
        }
    }, {
        safe: true,
        upsert: true
    },
    function(err, model) {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(model);
    }
);
```

But i 'm trying everything to add the bot to an existing API. I tried this one :

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({
        "_id": userId,
        "apis._id": apiId
    }, {
        $push: {
            "apis.$.bots": bot
        }
    },

    function(err, doc) {
        console.error("Error:", err);
        console.log("Doc:", doc);
    }
);
```

But i got this error shown :

CastError: Cast to undefined failed for value "[object Object]"